# How to check by filename if a image is in use on a website (all pages)

Tags: jquery

for a small kind of image-gallery, I need to check if an image is in use in a set of HTML-pages.

The ID of the image could be different on every page, so I can't check if a selector-id exists what I normally will do in this case but this won't work `if($("#IMGAEID"). length){`

Is it possile to do a kind like that `if( $($(body).find(myimagename) ). length){` - or in a better way

I must check if the image is in use with a `<img....` tag or for background-style or something else.

How I can do that if I only know the name of the image.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each` on all the image tag found and then compare them with the image name you want. You can get the image name from its src attribute which can be obtained using `.attr()`. Here in the snippet we are looking for an image named imagename3.jpg

```js
var key='imagename3.jpg';
$('img').each(function(){
if($(this).attr('src')==key)
console.log($(this).attr('src'))
});

var a=document.getElementById('bg').style;
var image=a['background-image'].split('(')[1].split(')')[0]
console.log(image)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="imagename0.jpg">
<img src="imagename1.jpg">
<img src="imagename2.jpg">
<img src="imagename3.jpg">
<img src="imagename4.jpg">
<div id="bg" style="background-image: url('imagename2.jpg')"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, good first idear - and how i should handle the background-images?